# Integrating Philips Hue with Home Assistant via Zigbee

Tags: zigbee, philips-hue, home-assistant

As Philips is going to force users to create accounts and share data online with them, I embarked on a journey to integrate my Philips Hue bulbs and light strips with [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) using a Zigbee adapter, and I'd love to share the process to help anyone looking to do the same.

This journey involved a series of adjustments and troubleshooting but eventually led to a successful integration, paving the way for a more centralized and flexible smart home setup. Please feel free to criticize my approach. I'm here to share and learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Initial Setup**

- Hypervisor Proxmox 8
- Virtual Machine Running Docker Host 24.0.5
- Docker Container running Home Assistant 2023.10.1
- Zigbee Adapter: [SONOFF Zigbee 3.0 USB Dongle Plus V2](https://sonoff.tech/product/gateway-and-sensors/sonoff-zigbee-3-0-usb-dongle-plus-e/)

**2. Pass-through USB Zigbee Adapter**

- Plugin Zigbee Adapter to physical server
- Pass-through the USB port to the VM in Proxmox via Hardware section of the VM, it is quite self-explaining and needs no re-boot of the VM
- Run `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id` in the VM to double-check your setup, it should be something like this:

```bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct  6 22:54 usb-ITEAD_SONOFF_Zigbee_3.0_USB_Dongle_Plus_V2_20230324155149-if00 -> ../../ttyACM0
```

**3. Docker Compose Adjustments**

- Ensured the Docker container had necessary permissions to access the host's serial devices by modifying the docker-compose file.
- Here's a snippet of the docker-compose file used:

```yaml
    devices:
      - /dev/serial/by-id/usb-ITEAD_SONOFF_Zigbee_3.0_USB_Dongle_Plus_V2_20230324155149-if00:/dev/serial/by-id/usb-ITEAD_SONOFF_Zigbee_3.0_USB_Dongle_Plus_V2_20230324155149-if00
    volumes:
      - '/dev/serial/by-id:/dev/serial/by-id'
```

**4. Zigbee Home Automation (ZHA) Integration**

- The ZHA integration should detect the new adapter and guide you through a bunch of setup screens
- I faced screens asking for Zigbee type, Port, Port Speed, and Data Flow Control. Selected `EZSP` for Zigbee type, provided the USB path `/dev/serial/by-id/...` mentioned above, set the Port Speed to `115200`, and Data Flow Control to `Software`.
- After that the setup was done

**5. Bulb Pairing**

- Attempted to pair bulbs via ZHA integration, but the bulbs weren’t discovered initially.
- Ensured the bulbs were removed from the previously used Philips Hue bridge by removing them in the Philips Hue app (this is very important)
- Checked and experimented with Zigbee channels to avoid any interference, ensuring a clear channel for communication.
- Pairing bulbs and light strips involved some waiting but worked reliably
- Pairing dimmer switches required to set them in pairing mode:

  - If the switch has been paired with a hue bridge before, you need to find the reset button and reset it
  - The reset button is within a small hole you need to push hold with a needle or other pointy device
  - New switches have that underneath the battery cover
  - After that press and hold the power button for 3 seconds until the LED on the front of the switch starts to blink

**6. Scenes and automations**

- Go to Settings > Automations & Scenes > Scenes and a scenes you want to activate, when pushing a button on your switch (or in the app)
- Add all bulbs which should be active and set the colors, brightness etc.
- Then go to Settings > Automations & Scenes > Automations and create one automation for each button
- The trigger is the button, the action is the scene

Comment: "Ensured the bulbs were removed from the previously used Philips Hue bridge by removing them in the Philips Hue app" - click the Reset button, not Remove